# Node Webkit How to save the value of a div as a .txt file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, node-webkit

I've been through a lot of tutorials and I can never get this to work:

I want to save the content of a div (with contenteditable enabled) to a .txt file with node webkit. That part looks like this:

```
<div id="editor" class="textbox" contenteditable></div>
```

And I have the input field that allows me to select the file:

```
<input type="file" nwsaveas="untitled.txt" style="display:none;"/>
```

However I can't find any resources on how to save the value of the editor div as a .txt file on the user's computer.

I tried this tuts plus tutorial that briefly explains it however it didn't seem to work when I tried it on my own project: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-html5-desktop-apps-with-node-webkit--net-36296

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make file dialog open with emulating `click` event of an `input`, then get `innerHTML` of `#editor`, and finally use node's `fs.writeFile` to save content.

Here is full working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var initInputFile = function() {
    document.getElementById('inputFile').addEventListener('change', function() {
        var path = this.value;   //get fullpath of chosen file
        var content = document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML;  //get editor's content
        content = (' ' + content).slice(1);   //hack to prevent strange bug of saving just half of the content
        require('fs').writeFile(path, content, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('done');
        });

        var wrapper = document.getElementById('inputFileWrapper');
        wrapper.innerHTML = wrapper.innerHTML;  //hack to make "change" event trigger...
        initInputFile();                            //...when choosing the same file
    });
}
window.onload = function() {
    initInputFile();
    document.getElementById('saveBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        event.initMouseEvent('click');
        document.getElementById('inputFile').dispatchEvent(event);
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="editor" class="textbox" style="width:400px; height:100px;" contenteditable></div>
    <div id="inputFileWrapper" style="display:none;">
        <input type="file" id="inputFile" nwsaveas="untitled.txt"/>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="saveBtn" value="Save" />

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.